# Run Java Class with External Dependencies from Command Prompt?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I was wondering whether it is possible to run a Java class that uses external libraries using the Windows Command Prompt.

I have the following minimal example Java class, where I just use the [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to create a JSON file using the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writeValue(new File("test.json"), "test");

        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }
}
```

I compiled this project originally using Maven in the IntelliJ IDE, and I set the proper dependencies for `Jackson` in the `pom.xml` file.

I then wanted to run the resultant `Test.class` file with the Command Prompt with the following command:

```
java Test
```

Resulting in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
        at Test.main(Test.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 1 more
```

I'm not very experienced with Java, and I've only ever used IDEs that handle most of the linking in the background for me. I just know that one can run a Java class in the Windows CMD using the `java` command, and I'm assuming that here it's telling me that it can't link the `Jackson` library properly.

Most of the [existing simillar questions out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919266/java-command-line-run-with-external-libraries) usually ask about user-made classes, I haven't yet been able to find a solution for external dependencies such as those defined by Maven.

Is it possible to run a Java class that uses external libraries using the Windows Command Prompt?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The libraries (JAR files likely) must be installed on a location that makes them available on the Classpath. The JVM will then look and find them as needed when running your app.

Comment: So, if I was originally using those libraries via the Maven dependencies, does that mean I need to download the library source code, compile it and then put the paths to those JAR files in the environment variable?

Comment: Also, is there a way to expand the `NoClassDefFoundError` message I get when attempting to run the `Test` class? I found the JAR files for the class definitions for the `Jackson` library, but I need to know exactly which one of the JAR files the program is looking for...

Comment: A Maven repository provides JAR file for the needed library, no need for source code. If your app needs a library (a dependency), then you must have that library available at runtime. You can bundle that library with your app OR you can put that library in a place on the deployment computer where it will be available to the JVM on the classpath. **Your choice: bundle or install.** Use the `scope` element in the `dependency` element of your Maven POM file.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for your reply; Bundle would be my choice here. I found the JAR files for the Jackson library, where should I put them so that they are able to be included when I try to run the `Test.class` file? I tried putting them in the same folder, but they still can't be found. I tried using the `-cp` argument when issuing the `java` command, but I'm not sure what the proper syntax for that is. Most online sources say that I must separate the class path and the class name with a `:` character on Windows, but it's not working here. What is the proper syntax for the `-cp` argument?

Comment: You should configure your POM file to build a JAR with dependencies included. Those are the two purposes of Maven: (a) Locate, download, and install dependencies, and (b) manage the building of your app to produce a final artifact. Sounds like you need to study up on what Maven is, and how to use it. Seems like an annoying learning curve, but actually is time well spent. By the way, Gradle serves the same purposes as Maven (and uses Maven repositories to source dependencies), but is more flexible, using Groovy syntax rather than XML. Both Maven and Gradle are good tools, both are very popular.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for your reply; I think you may be misunderstanding what I'm trying to do here. I'm not building a JAR of my project with Maven, I built the `.class` file. And I'm only trying to run it via the Command Prompt, I'm not trying to run it with Maven. Is that what you're reffering to? Are you saying I can simply fit all the code from `Jackson` straight into the `Test.class`, and not have it link every time I want to run `Test.class`?

Comment: You said “bundle” is your choice! That means building your app as a final artifact that includes your own classes plus the classes of your dependency libraries. If “install” is actually your choice, then we already covered that: Install the dependency libraries in a place where they will appear on the classpath of your JVM at runtime. There are multiple ways to do that install, some are platform-specific. I’ve given you the concepts and terms you need to find a choose a way that works on Windows OS and meets your needs/preferences.

Comment: You’ve not worked through enough tutorials to understand the nature of Java apps. Start with the free tutorial provided by Oracle, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Duplicate of [*How can I create an executable/runnable JAR with dependencies using Maven?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time spent messing around with the Maven settings and some more searching, I think I found a solution to my issues.

I had some misconceptions about how exactly Maven works, and I was confusing `class` and `jar` files in this case. I had initially assumed that I would have to strichtly run the generated `Test.class` file in order to run my program via the Command Prompt.

However, as some have pointed out in the comments of my post (thanks Basil Bourque), Maven is capable of generating a `jar` file that contains everything required to run my program.

---

Here are the steps that worked for my specific setup in IntelliJ IDE, adapted from [the suggested post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-runnable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven):

1. Ensured that the correct dependencies are listed in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2. Added this section underneath the dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Test</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

3. Ran the `clean` Maven command under the `Lifecycle` category:

[image]

4. Ran the `compile` Maven command under the `Lifecycle` category:

[image]

5. Ran the `assembly:single` Maven command under the `assembly` plugin in the `Plugins` category:

[image]

---

After doing the steps above, in the `target` folder of my project there was now a `jar` file with the suffix `jar-with-dependencies`, which contains my program code alongside all the imported libraries.

I was able to run it from the Command Prompt by issuing:

```
java -jar *path_of_jar_file*
```

Thanks for all the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Maven anyway to build your project, you could also use maven to run it via the [exec-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). A very good [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-main-method) is available online.

Basically you just need to run your class like this:

```
    mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Test"
```