# Intellij not adding VTK library .dll dependency to Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, physics, vtk

I have installed [VTK](https://vtk.org/) for a physics simulation program called [Starfish](https://www.particleincell.com/starfish/) with its [Github](https://github.com/particleincell/Starfish). But I am **not asking for any physics help**, but rather **I am trying to add VTK as a library dependency** to Starfish so that it can be run on Intellij.

Starfish is written in Java and when I [installed VTK](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md#windows), and tried to add it in my IDE, but it doesn't work no matter what I do. The project throws: `java: package vtk does not exist` whenever I run the project's main or try to build it. The whole VTK dependency is not recognized. The VTK library is composed of `dll` type files and there are no JAR files for it. Also, there does not seem to be a Maven dependency for it as well, and Starfish is not a Maven project.

**I have VTK version 9.2.2.**

I have tried:

1. Adding VTK as a module dependency under the project structure > project settings > modules > dependencies > choosing the path of the VTK installation
2. Adding VTK as a library under project structure > project settings > libraries
3. Adding the path to VTK `/bin` via `-Djava.library.path="C:/path/to/VTK` as a VM option in the run config of Intellij
4. Adding VTK to the global libraries under project structure > Platform settings > global libraries
5. Restarting and invalidating the cache
6. Deleting the `.idea` directory and restarting
7. Searching online for many days like stackoverflow, VTK forums, IntelliJ's forums, etc

I am out of ideas on what to try next. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One possible solution would be to create a JAR file containing the VTK library and then add that JAR file as a dependency to your project.

Comment: @SANN3 I created the jar file using https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146453/10821284 and then I added it to my project as a module and a library and even restarted, but it still doesn't recognize VTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VTK is [available as a Maven dependency](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/vtk-9-1-available-as-maven-dependency/9371). You can add Maven support for your project and include VTK in your pom.xml into dependencies section.

- Right-click on a project root in [Project View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html) and select `Add Framework Support... | Maven`
- Add the content below into pom.xml

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jzy3d-snapshots</id>
            <name>Jzy3d Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://maven.jzy3d.org/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jzy3d-releases</id>
            <name>Jzy3d Releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.jzy3d.org/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
            <artifactId>vtk-java-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

- Click on `Reload All Maven Projects` in Maven tool window:
  [image]

Now imports to the VTK library should be resolved properly.